# Keycloak : Customize OpenID Endpoint /auth to /authorize

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak, openid

I looked for how to personalize keycloak endpoints /auth to /authorize, I searched at the keycloak UI level but without success.

For information, the endpoint /auth is exposed here using this URL https:////realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration.

I tried Keycloak UI and Keycloak REST API.
Modify and Rebuild keycloak source code is not a good idea. I don't know if we can create a keycloak extension in order to expose new endpoints /authorize?

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards,